# How to set attribute in nifi processor using pure Python not jython?

Tags: python, apache-nifi, nipyapi

How to set properties (attribute) in nifi processor using pure Python in ExecuteStreamCommand processor
I don't want to use Jython, I know it can be done using pinyapi. But don't know how to do it. I just want to create an attribute using Python script.

Comment: with ExecuteStreamCommand you could change only the content of the flow file

Answer (score 0):

> How to set properties(attribute) in nifi processor using pure python in ExecuteStreamCommand processor I don't want to use Jython

You can't do it from `ExecuteStreamCommand`. The Python script doesn't have the ability to interact with the `ProcessSession`, which is what it would need to set an attribute. You'd need to set up some operations after it to add the attributes like an `UpdateAttribute` instance.